# how to Avoid open the same window twice in a new tab in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to avoid to open same window of existing website(window) in new tab

> for eg..   if i have a page www.mysite.com/page1.aspx if i copy this
>   URL and paste in new tab of the browser than  a popup or message
>   should be appear(alert-- you have already open this website)

**Note:** if we reload or refresh the previous page than alter should not be appear .means only one page  can be open at a time

It should be done in scripting only, i need your valuable advice
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can stop browser from opening another instance. You need to look for other options.

Comment: Shekhar.... actually i just want to show the message if second instance is created....

Answer (score 0):

Create a cookie, set its value to true on page load and false on log off.
check if a cookie is true and same page loaded show your message.

Comment: hi...but in this approach..if i reload the same page again message will display...(bcz when i reload or refresh page than it goes for page load and on all pages it will show message --) how to prevent message to show on very first instance of the browser for same page

Comment: @user3647344 bro this won't be possible, even if you try using server side code it is not possible.